# Display generated SQL queries from JPA entities (without running the application)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I would like to build a tool to help developers/architects to detect potential slow or bad  queries in their applications.

Complex generated SQL queries due to wrong JPA usage are quite very common in projects I saw.
And people don't really use SQL debugging feature we can have in Hibernate tool.

I would like to provide static analysis of a JPA application with warnings (Sonar like rule) when generated SQL queries are a bit too complex

Does anybody know how I can do that with Hibernate?